# Вопрос о работе интерпретатора или JVM\CLR !

Tags: clr, jvm, компилятор

Доброго дня всем ! Сразу к делу: в любой многозадачной ОС прежде чем запустить любое приложение нужно создать "процесс", у которого там своё адресное пространство, хотя бы один поток и т.п... В этот "процесс" ОС засунет откомпилированные в машинные инструкции файлы (допустим, ПО было написано на С++), и данный процесс начнет выполнение, то есть заработает приложение. А как же тогда работает приложение написанное на Python, ведь там за работу возмется интепретатор, или Java ПО где *.class - это файл инструкции для JVM (если не ошибаюсь), тогда нужно в "процесс" поместить саму JVM, или ещё до создания "процесса" JVM переведёт файл в машинный код? Тогда получается интерпретатор Питона постепенно переводит файл в машинные команды и это засовывается в "процесс", у него же нет JITтера как у Java\C#? Буду всем очень благодарен за просветление ...

Comment: Никто не в курсе ?

Comment: Расставил от балды запятые, кажется, получилось немного грамотней, надеюсь, вы не против.

Comment: @Fike - я даже вам благодарен !

Comment: Может кто хотя бы литературку подбросит по данному вопросу ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложение, написанное на интерпретируемом языке (например, интерпретируемом диалекте Питона), запускается не само. Операционная система настраивается так, чтобы при запуске приложения запускался на самом деле интерпретатор, которому указывается исходный текст через параметры, и он начинает его выполнять.

То же происходит для `.class`: с точки зрения операционной системы, запускается не сам `.class`, а Java VM, которая в свою очередь запускает JIT-компилятор, и передаёт результат на выполнение.

С .NET-программами всё немного сложнее: в начале программы расположен stub, который загружает библиотеку `mscoree.dll`, которая уже отвечает за JIT-компиляцию и запуск скомпилированного кода. Более точно и подробно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6632609/276994).

Comment: @VladD Спасибо большое за ответ ...

Comment: @Vladimir_X: Пожалуйста!